# GNOME Software won't install Google Chrome

Tags: xubuntu, deb, gnome-software

This problem always seems to happen to me on a new install of Xubuntu on my machine.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04.3 and using GNOME Software version 3.20.5.

This is on a fresh install.

I just ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

I downloaded the latest version of Google Chrome browser. Then I double click it and it opens in GNOME software. When I double-click install, it gives me a progress bar for a second or two, then resets the install button. I keep mashing install, but the same process repeats, and Google Chrome does not install.

What should I do?

Comment: For 16.04 and newer `apt` instead of  `apt-get` (and with `apt` the new `full-upgrade` is used instead of `dist-upgrade`). In any case your second command misses the `apt-get` so, if this isn't a typo, you didn't fully updated your system.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `dpkg` to install Google Chrome?

I suspect you put your Google Chrome package in `~/Downloads` and you downloaded it from [chrome.google.com](http://chrome.google.com). Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Enter your password when prompted and that should be it!

Comment: I did subsequently install by using dpkg. But I am still curious what is going on with GNOME Software. Really the question is, why does GNOME-Software fail to install chrome, not "How do I install chrome on linux".

Answer (score 1):

Try `dpkg` as suggested by *Cynplytholowazy* or install **GDebi** first and open the downloaded `.deb` package with GDebi.