# Install button in Software Center does nothing when I try to install Chrome & other apps

Tags: google-chrome, downloads

I just completed a new PC build, and installed Ubuntu 17.04.

The first thing I did was try to download Google Chrome, and lo and behold, the install button doesn't work.

I have seen this bug elsewhere, but I didn't really get the fix. (I have no idea how to work Ubuntu besides being spoon-fed tutorials.)

I also tried to download the Minecraft launcher, and there are many different solutions, most using a PPA. None of them worked. One of them had an install link in the software tab of Ubuntu, and I had the same glitch as with chrome. This is really troubling me and I need some help! Thanks!

Comment: I suggest a better title. It sounds as if you can download without any problem. Why are you downloading .deb rather than using the ubuntu repositories ? I highly suggest chromium rather than chrome unless there is some feature you need in chrome that is lacking in chromium (very unlikely).

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu

Comment: Chrome requires `libappindicator1`

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957540/gnome-software-wont-install-google-chrome